# cert-manager: Let's Encrypt HTTP01 challenge with nginx (without ingress)

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

Is it somehow possible to use `cert-manager` with an ACME HTTP01 challenge (specifically Let's Encrypt) and let `cert-manager` provide the solution via a normal Nginx server instead of Nginx ingress?

So technically it would be enough if `cert-manager` would write the challenge solution to a file, serving it via Nginx is something I can configure manually.

Comment: I haven't done this, but I _think_ you can create a [Certificate resource](https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts) manually and then use the created Kubernetes Secret in your own Nginx deployment.

Comment: @scnewman Yeah, I was also wondering if the are compatible. But there's one step before that that will fail: the ACME challenge (see accepted answer). So I gave up on this and will install an ingress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are trying to make cert-manager to write the challenge solution to a file.

If you dig a bit in the code of cert-maanger, you can see that cert-manager after receiving the challenge, creates a pod (http server), ingress and service for it.

There is no way to get the challenge and write it to a file without modifying the code.

Comment: OK, thanks for the information. I will setup an ingress and use the official guide (https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/ingress/).